# How to toggle parts of ContantPage in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: layout, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, controls

I have `ContantPage` for adding new object to database. And one part of this page can be two sets of controls depending on state of `ToggleButton`.

How to implement such thing with Xamarin.Forms keeping in mind that I need to access values of this optional part from `ContantPage`?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have two Layout views (e.g. StackLayout) one with the toggle off controls and the other with the toggle on controls.

Then bind the IsVisible property of the StackLayouts to the toggled property of the switch (one bound to be visible when toggled on, the other when toggled off).